# Rails confirmation dialog text based on select_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, confirm

I'm building a form with 2 fields and one submit button. Basically, it's an update on the status field, and the form has the current state and the other field is a select input with possible options for the update. When selecting this new state, I have a confirmation dialog like this:

```
submit_tag("submit", class: 'btn', data: { confirm: t("are you sure?", { current: model.state, to: new_state}) })
```

The `t` inside the data is for the translations, and `current` and `to` are the hash values that I have to pass in as parameters for building the message: "Are you sure you want to change from state1 to state2?". But I was wondering how can I use the `select_tag` value as the text for the `to` hash key.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with JS. Your button submit should be a type "button" with onclick for call a JS function where you can valid the value of select, launch de alert and submit the form.

for select the select value:

```
document.getElementById("selectId").value();
```

and for submit you can use:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```